# Compare url link and url text in email body and reject as SPAM

Tags: email, spam, spamassassin, filter, fortigate

Email body:

```
... <a href="url">text</a> ...
```

Is it possible check if **text** is url in email body, then compare **url** and **text** and reject as SPAM if they differ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea.
Virtually all email delivered through commercial platforms rewrite the email links in order to be able to count clicks. The links in such email lead to a redirection service that records which link of which email has been clicked and then redirect to the original link.

This includes newsletters, transactional email and many other legit email traffic.

Whenever the visible part of the a tag is a url, there will be a mismatch.

This check alone would lead to way too many false positives.